# Two list-questions: using 'empty?' and inserting several list items at once

Tags: netlogo

I want to use a list to keep track of and trigger debt-payments for turtles. The idea is to have lists (debt-1, debt-2, ...) which are initially empty and then filled with payable installments during the model run. So far, I'm setting up the list like this:

```
set debt-1 []
set debt-2 [] 
...
```

Next, I want to populate some of the lists with four data points at a time. So far, I have this solution, with 'debt-payment' being a numeric value:

```
  ifelse empty? debt-1 [
    set debt-1 fput debt-payments debt-1
    set debt-1 fput debt-payments debt-1
    set debt-1 fput debt-payments debt-1
    set debt-1 fput debt-payments debt-1
  ]
  [ifelse empty? debt-2 [
    set debt-2 fput debt-payments debt-2
    set debt-2 fput debt-payments debt-2
    set debt-2 fput debt-payments debt-2
    set debt-2 fput debt-payments debt-2
    ]

  [etc.]
```

Question 1a: is there a more elegant way to input four items with the same value in the lists?
Question 1b: is there a more elegant way to identify the emtpy? list and fill it with items?

Next, I want to use those lists to determine payments for the turtles. In a separate command, I want turtles to ask if any of the debt-lists contain any items, and if so, subtract their wealth by the value of item 0, and then remove item 0 from the list. So far I have this:

```
ask turtles [
  if not empty? debt-1 [
    set wealth (wealth - (item 0 debt-1))
    set debt-1 remove-item 0 debt-2
  ]

[etc]
```

When running the model, however, this code returns the error "EMPTY? expected input to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead." I guess my issue is that debt-1 doesn't return 'empty', but 0 instead. My question is how do I make it so that the list is perceived as being empty while it has no items in it? Or, if there is another way of achieving the same outcome (turtles recognizing that one of the debt-lists is activated/full, and then subtracting those values from their wealth.

Comment: This is too many questions all at once. On Stack Overflow you're expected to ask one question at a time. I'll answer your first question: `n-values` is useful for making a list consisting of repeated values.

Comment: Thanks, Seth, and apologies for posting multiple questions! N-values worked for me and for the second question I actually found a mistake in my code which I was able to fix. 
Cheers, 
Marius